# How do i remove blue color from selected rows in aggrid

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

[image]

I'm trying to remove the blue color to the selected rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it easily in CSS

The selected row has class `.ag-row-selected` and you should override native style

Use the next style:

```
.ag-row-selected {
    background-color: unset !important;
}
```

I just added style in index.html

here result:
[image]

WORKING EXAMPLE: https://plnkr.co/edit/JOKkg1LcjihbCZSi

Comment: Hello Avinash! if my solution helps you please accept my answer like correct